# Selenium waiting for AJAX in Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, nunit

I've been using Selenium to automate website testing. Part of the tests involves waiting for AJAX requests to finish. I've been using this line to do that with jQuery 1.4:

```
selenium.WaitForCondition("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active == 0", "5000");
```

It worked fine in Chrome and Firefox 4, but not IE9. Then I upgraded to jQuery 1.5, and it magically stopped working in Chrome. I've tried the following variations, but none of them work:

```
selenium.WaitForCondition("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.active == 0", "5000");
selenium.WaitForCondition("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().jQuery.ajax.active == 0", "5000");
selenium.WaitForCondition("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().$.active == 0", "5000");
selenium.WaitForCondition("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().$.ajax.active == 0", "5000");
```

The SeleniumException is that it cannot read property `active` or `ajax` of undefined, so I guess it's somehow not able to get to jQuery. My colleague is running the same tests on Firefox 4, and they pass.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently everything in Selenium can be fixed by throwing in random `Thread.Sleep()s`. The window hadn't finished loading in some cases, that's why `$` was undefined. I put a sleep before the wait, and it works fine now.

I had to use the following line:

```
selenium.WaitForCondition("selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().$.active == 0", "5000");
```

Even though people are saying I should have used `$.ajax.active` if I'm using jQuery 1.5, it's undefined for me, whereas `$.active` works.