# Chromedriver Slow on Javascript Execution

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

**Background**
I'm using Selenium Webdriver .Net for coding and MSTest is being used from within Visual Studio 2012 and MSTest cmd in order to run the tests.

I have encountered a strange issue in Chromedriver, where Javascript execution extremely slowdown the test execcution. Eg:- I'm using javascript to WaitForAjax, ScrollToElemet and functions in my tests.

When I execute one test at a time, it executes very fast. But when I execute them as a suite, The first test executes fast and starting from the second test, the execution slows down significantly.

**My Configuration is as follows:**

- Chrome Version: 41.0.2272.118 m
- Chrome Driver: 2.14
- Selenium .Net: 2.44
- Windows: 7 Enterprise 64 bit

Any help would be appreciated to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Here's the functions as requested

```
public static IWebElement ScrollToElement(this IWebElement element)
    {
        try
        {
            IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
            executor.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(" + element.Location.X + "," + (element.Location.Y - 500) + ");");
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return element;
    }

public static void WaitForAjax(this IWebDriver driver, int timeout = 60)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor javascript = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        if (javascript == null)
        {
            // Log a warning
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
                wait.Until(drv => (bool)(drv as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"));
            }
            catch (WebDriverTimeoutException ex)
            {
                Assert.Inconclusive(string.Format("Ajax Calls Didn't Complete After: {0} seconds. Exception message: {1}", timeout, ex.Message));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"The first test executes fast and starting from the second test, the execution slows down significantly."_ -- Makes me wonder if the tests aren't broken...

Comment: Is there a way you can share `WaitForAjax`, `ScrollToElemet` functions? wondering if they are doing something strange

Comment: I dont think the tests are broken, I have selected different set of tests together. But everytime, from the second test, execution slows down. note that I close the browser session after each test and start a new one in the next. I have added the code for WaitForAjax, ScrollToElemet functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium waiting for AJAX in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469722/selenium-waiting-for-ajax-in-chrome)